# fixing date format in textbox on pageload

Tags: vb.net

i have to Fix the date format MM/dd/yyyy on page load in vb.net in textbox
but as soon as the page get refresh due to changes made in other textbox it get changed to other fromats like dd/MM/yyyy

what shall i do

Date

HeatNo

javascript
function isNumber1(evt, element) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if (
                           (charCode != 45 ) && (charCode != 47 ) &&     // 
                           (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                      return false;
                    return true;
        }

//to get date on pageload the code is as

Private Sub getdateshift()
        txtDate.AutoPostBack = False
        If Now.Hour = 0 OrElse Now.Hour = 1 OrElse Now.Hour = 2 OrElse Now.Hour = 3 OrElse Now.Hour = 4 OrElse Now.Hour = 5 Then
            txtDate.Text = Now.Date.AddDays(-1)
        Else
            txtDate.Text = Now.Date
        End If

```
    dte = Now
    Select Case dte.Hour
        Case 6 To 13
            Shift = "A"
        Case 14 To 21
            Shift = "B"
        Case 9 To 17
            Shift = "G"
        Case Else
            Shift = "C"
    End Select
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    rblShift.ClearSelection()
    For i = 0 To rblShift.Items.Count - 1
        If rblShift.Items(i).Text = Shift Then
            rblShift.Items(i).Selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    dte = Nothing
    Shift = Nothing
End Sub
```

txtDate.Text=Now.Date  //to get current date of system

CDate(txtDate.Text)   //to pass value to function

Format(CDate(txtDate.Text),"MM/dd/yyyy") //to save data in database

or

Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text) //to pass value in database and to function

whenever the txtHeat textbox changed txtDate format should not changed and also when form saved then also txtDate not get changed

Comment: You can use .ToString(<format>) to print time. Eg DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Comment: thnku i have done this thing already but format is not getting fixed on page load sometime it fixed and sometime not,so i had use                                                                 Dim sFormat As System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo = New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo()                    sFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy"                                       
 txtDate.Text = Format(Convert.ToDateTime(Now.Date, sFormat), "MM/dd/yyyy")                                                                                                         it had work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had use following code in the required function from where the page is loading again

Dim sFormat As System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo = New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo()

sFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            txtDate.Text = Format(Convert.ToDateTime(Now.Date, sFormat), "dd-MM-yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, something similar happened to me just a couple days ago, I was retrieving a date from a DB and putting it on a textbox, and VB keep changing the format and displaying MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm and I solved it with this line of code.

```
Textbox1.text=DateValue(DateSource.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Replace the DateSource for the variable or whatever has your date.  For some reason without the DateValue it throws an error, looks like Textbox autoformat when it recognizes is Time or Date.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = rwfGen.Connection.CmdObj                       
 my database is connect through an organisation server,then also will it work